# Linking Spring Boot container with Mongo DB container with username e password

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, docker

What is the best way to link a Mongo container with username and password inside a docker spring boot container?

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables in your application yaml. Something like this :

```
mongo:
  username: ${MONGO_USERNAME}
  password: ${MONGO_PASSWORD}
```

And then passing it to your container with environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running both mongo and your application in containers you could consider using something like docker-compose to start both containers and you will be able to reach the mongo container from your application container using the container name. e.g:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: "my-app:latest"
    build: .
    command: --spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://db/test
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - "db"
  db:
    image: "mongo:latest"
```

You can then run `docker-compose up`